# Pycharm and Python; all prints saved to a exported file (csv/txt, etc.)

Tags: python, pycharm, output

Currently I am running a python code all day. And what it basically does is print a data frame on pycharm's Run tool window. The run tool window basically displays output generated by the application.

I want to know if its possible to save the entire output generated in one day to a txt file.

Thank yo for your time,

Comment: Since the output is generated by the running Python code, it may be easier to save the output by creating a file to log your printed output - i.e. where you print output, you write it to your log file.

Comment: instead of saving printing, have you considered using logging module and output to a file? here is a simple example....https://pl.python.org/docs/lib/node294.html

Comment: you can also refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python) to redirect stdout to a file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ python yourapp.py > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also save a script output to a file with PyCharm UI, for specific Run Configuration:

[image]